# How to calculate percentages of values in specific rows of a file?

Tags: awk

I built a file where I have headers with generic IDs that identify multiple alignments and on the next rows the genome IDs that correspond to that alignment ID. Along with the genome IDs I have numbers that I would like to convert in percentages, adding the value of the percentage as a third column, according to the example below:

ORIGINAL FILE:

```
>Alignment_1
GCA_910584205.1  13
GCA_003584705.1  7
>Alignment_2
GCA_002361735.1  168
GCA_002492725.1  2880
GCA_002492725.1  2880
>Alignment_3
GCA_900540295.1  165
GCA_002490525.1  125
```

FINAL FILE:

```
>Alignment_1
GCA_910584205.1  13 65%
GCA_003584705.1  7 35%
>Alignment_2
GCA_002361735.1  168 3%
GCA_002492725.1  2880 49%
GCA_002492725.1  2880 49%
>Alignment_3
GCA_900540295.1  165 57%
GCA_002490525.1  125 43%
```

I know awk can be used to calculate the percentages of values in a column in comparison with the total value of the column but how can I get these percentages by groups of alignments delimited by the headers?

Comment: How to round the numbers because I see in second group sum of percentage is 101%

Comment: A percentage of _what_? I am guessing you want us to sum the numbers in each section and then print the what percentage _of that sum_ each number represents, but it would really help if you could make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/>/ {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    key = $0
    cnt = tot = 0
    next
}
{
    ids[++cnt] = $1
    vals[cnt]  = $2
    tot += $2
}
END { prt() }

function prt(           i) {
    print key
    for ( i=1; i<=cnt; i++ ) {
        print ids[i], vals[i], ceil( (tot ? vals[i] / tot : 0) * 100 )"%"
    }
}

function ceil(x,        y) {
    y = int(x)
    return ( x>y ? y+1 : y )
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>Alignment_1
GCA_910584205.1 13 65%
GCA_003584705.1 7 35%
>Alignment_2
GCA_002361735.1 168 3%
GCA_002492725.1 2880 49%
GCA_002492725.1 2880 49%
>Alignment_3
GCA_900540295.1 165 57%
GCA_002490525.1 125 44%
```

For info on `ceil()`, see [roundup-function-in-unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432680/roundup-function-in-unix/37437080#37437080).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @Ed Morton! In fact, I realised it would be better for me to get these numbers in the original format (without rounding and multiplying by 100 +"%"), so I ended with this final version of your code:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/>/ {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    key = $0
    cnt = tot = 0
    next
}
{
    ids[++cnt] = $1
    vals[cnt]  = $2
    tot += $2
}
END { prt() }

function prt(           i) {
    print key
    for ( i=1; i<=cnt; i++ ) {
        print ids[i], vals[i], ceil( (tot ? vals[i] / tot : 0) * 100 )"%"
    }
}

function ceil(x,        y) {
    y = int(x)
    return ( x>y ? y+1 : y )
}
```